# The definition of a cardinal number

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I’m confused about the definition of a cardinal number.

We say the cardinal of a set $A$ is just the minimum element of the set of ordinals equinumerous to $A$.

But if two ordinals are equinumerous to $A$ does that not make the ordinals the same since every ordinal is the successor of the previous?

Also if the ordinals equinumerous to $A$ are all the same size then why do we pick the minimum in particular to be the cardinal of $A$ and how does this miminum ordinal actually correspond to the size/cardinal of the set $A$?

Comment: You keep talking about "size".

Comment: Could you edit your penultimate paragraph's grammar to make its question clearer? Choosing the minimum equinumerous ordinal, or equivalently the intersection of such ordinals, is very natural; see also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number) concept, which doesn't require all sets to be equinumerous to an ordinal (a claim equivalent in ZF to the axiom of choice).

Comment: I always thought the cardinal number of a set was the number of elements, wth care needed for infinite sets?

Comment: @herbsteinberg In first-order theories without urelements where everything is a set, we instead choose a set representative of sets being a certain size.

Comment: @J.G. My math education did not include first order theories, only basic set theory (Bourbaki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if two ordinals are equinumerous to $A$ does that not make the ordinals the same since every ordinal is the successor of the previous?

No. Both $\omega$ and $\omega + 1 = \omega \cup \{\omega\}$ are equinumerous to $\omega$, but they are not the same.

> if the ordinals equinumerous to $A$ are all the same size then why do we pick the minimum in particular to be the cardinal of $A$

Because it's convenient and always exists. There isn't a second-minimum ordinal equinumerous to $7$, for instance. On the other hand, there isn't a *maximum* ordinal equinumerous to $\omega$ (all ordinals below $\omega_1$ are equinumerous to it). So what other choice do you propose?

> how does this miminum ordinal actually correspond to the size/cardinal of the set $A$?

It's the smallest ordinal that has the same size as $A$. That's it.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thank you. And to clarify, for finite sets there’s only one ordinal equinumerous to it?

Comment: @Anteater23 That's correct.